# MySQL Query 3 Table Inner Joins Only Returning 1 Row

Tags: mysql, magento, inner-join

I am creating some custom reporting in a Magento module, and I am struggling with the SQL on this one. I have put the SQL below, and basically, I want this to return a row for each row in the 'donor' table. It is basically getting the total value of sales of products that have a certain attribute.

```
SELECT b.entity_id AS 'Car ID', b.car_name AS 'Car Name', b.car_purchase_price AS 'Car Purchased For', SUM(s.price) AS 'Total Sales' 
FROM sales_flat_order_item AS s 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS c ON s.sku = c.entity_id 
INNER JOIN bs_donor AS b ON c.value = b.entity_id 
WHERE c.attribute_id = '971'
```

This works, but return only 1 row, even thought there are around 20 in the bs_donor table, and it also returns, what looks like, a total of sales for all products, not just the ones that have that particular attribute set. If I add this to the end of the query:

```
AND c.value = '50'
```

It gets the correct data, and is exactly what I need, but obviously just for the bs_donor row that has an ID of '50' or whatever I set there. I am assuming there is an error in the inner joins, and have tried using nested sub-query's, but just get lost.

I think it may be because I am getting data FROM sales_flat_order_item, instead of bs_donor, but I just can't get it running any other way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the order in which you do the joins, such that the `bs_donor` table appears first.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to ensure that every record from `bs_donor` appears in the result set.

```
SELECT b.entity_id AS 'Car ID',
       SUM(s.price) AS 'Total Sales' 
FROM bs_donor b
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int c
    ON c.value = b.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item s
   ON s.sku = c.entity_id
WHERE c.attribute_id = '971'
GROUP BY b.entity_id
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Tim! Thank you very much for the solution, and the explanation! Always helps to know for next time.

Comment: I suspect it's more about the inclusion of a GROUP BY clause than the order of the joins. Besides, the first join IS an inner join!!

Comment: I think they change every time you log in don't they!?!!

Comment: Not sure, the above worked for what I needed though. What changes whenever you login?